# How I can change a lot of data for one column at one time?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, types

I have an old database, one of its tables contains many columns and one of its columns called **oper** and its type is varchar and I have more that 180,000 rows in this table and the value for this column can be one of these :

```
first
second
third
fourth
fifth
```

now I updated my table and make the data type is int. So if I want to insert the old data I can't because the different between types ( int - string ).

I need some way to loop throw table rows and check for the value for **oper**

if old value equal "first" copy the row and change first to 1 and put this row in new table

if old value equal "second" copy the row and change first to 2 and put this row in new table

and so on .....

Is there any way that I can do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you want to insert into the new table from your old table.

```
INSERT INTO NewTable (Col1, Col2, Col3, Oper) --Oper is an int, right?

    SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, 
           CASE Oper
              WHEN  'first' THEN 1
              WHEN  'second' THEN 2
              WHEN 'third' THEN 3
              WHEN 'fourth' THEN 4
              WHEN 'fifth' THEN 5
           ELSE -1 END
    FROM OldTable
```